# Postgres + EJB3 pre-allocation size error

Tags: ejb-3.0, jpa-2.0, glassfish-3, postgresql-9.1

I am having problem with sequence in postgres and jpa

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.EntityExistsException:
Exception Description: The sequence named [shp_users_seq] is setup incorrectly.  Its increment does not match its pre-allocation size.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:443)
        at com.sun.enterprise.container.common.impl.EntityManagerWrapper.persist(EntityManagerWrapper.java:269)
        at base.data.provider.beans.session.DAOImpl.createUser(DAOImpl.java:18)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rule is : the increment size of the sequence is the value of the allocationSize in jpa:
I had this setting:which is wrong:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "User_Seq_Gen", 
                   sequenceName = "shp_users_seq", allocationSize=999)
```

corrected according to this:

```
@SequenceGenerator(name = "User_Seq_Gen", 
                   sequenceName = "shp_users_seq" ,allocationSize=1)
```

because the increment size of the sequence is 1:

```
 shopper=> \d shp_users_seq;
        Sequence "public.shp_users_seq"
    Column     |  Type   |        Value
---------------+---------+---------------------
 sequence_name | name    | shp_users_seq
 last_value    | bigint  | 1
 start_value   | bigint  | 1
 increment_by  | bigint  | 1
 max_value     | bigint  | 9223372036854775807
 min_value     | bigint  | 1
 cache_value   | bigint  | 1
 log_cnt       | bigint  | 0
 is_cycled     | boolean | f
 is_called     | boolean | t
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the start value for the sequence to at least the same size as you use for the attribute *allocationSize* of the *@SequenceGenerator* annotation.

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE seq_name
 ...
 START WITH 100;
```

See http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg03461.html for details on this.